# Options to display only snapshot volumes for lvs

Tags: lvm

Please consider the following configuration:

```
Hard Disk: /dev/sdb  (Size 10 GB)
VG: vg_root on /dev/sdb
THIN_POOL thin_pool occupying the whole physical extent
lvcreate -y --extents 100%free --thin vg_root/thin_pool

Thin volume on the thin pool
lvcreate --name lv_1 --virtualsize 1GB --thinpool vg_root/thin_pool

Another thin volume on the thin_pool
lvcreate --name lv_2 --virtualize 2GB --thinpool vg_root/thin_pool
mount and create a file of 1 GB on the volume

Snapshot volume for lv_2
lvcreate -y --setactivationskip n --snapshot --thinpool vg_root/thin_pool vg_root/lv_2 --name snapshot1
mount and create a file of 250MB on the volume
```

Is there a way through lvs to only display snapshot volumes : snapshot1 and snapshot2.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snapshots are identified with an `s` as the first character of the `lv_attr` field. You can use the `-S` selection to filter on the `lv_attr` value. The following command should do the trick:

```
lvs -S 'lv_attr =~ ^s'
```